# In left- or right-rotation for arrays, where did those conventions for the directions come from?

Tags: computer-science

This is a [repost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54996109/in-left-or-right-rotation-where-did-those-conventions-for-the-directions-come) from another exchange.

I was going to write a paper about code to rotate elements in an array, but I realized I have no idea why rotation towards the start of the array is “left” and “right” goes towards the end. I’ve seen horizontal tape diagrams of arrays, with elements going left-to-right (i.e. Western-culture reading order), but I don’t know if that’s the actual reason.

Maybe finding out who first came up with the convention would help.

Comment: ?? perhaps because English is written left-to-right, and therefore a list $[a,b,c,d,e]$ is written with the "start" on the left and the "finish" on the right.  As you said.  But of course, to answer this we need **references** not speculation.